# What permissions I need to get to wall post and group post?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I want to be able to wall post in my profile and post messages to my own Facebook Group. What permissions I need to get and how? (application Graph API)

```
import facebook

# Replace the access token with your own access token
access_token = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'

# Create a Facebook Graph API object using the access token
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)

# Define the message you want to post
message = 'Hello, World! This is a test message.'

# Post the message to your Facebook wall
graph.put_object(parent_object='me', connection_name='feed', message=message)
```

Comment: You can't post to user profiles via API any more. And for posting into a group, a group admin has to install your app in the group first.

Comment: I want to post to my profile only and I am admin and creator of the group